# Greek compounds: would "creation of knowledge" be sophogenesis or sophiagenesis?

Tags: ancient-greek

I'm writing an academic text and trying to find a nice term for the concept of creation/generation of knowledge.

The Greek  dictionaries I consulted seem to indicate sophia or sophos would work but I'm unsure how to merge them with genesis and don't have the linguistic  skills to interpret Greek grammar texts.

Comment: σοφία doesn't really mean knowledge so much as wisdom. Something like ἐπιστήμη or γνῶσις might be a better choice ([cf.](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/efts/sqldbs/WOODHOUSE/woodhouse.py?&pagenumber=472&qtype=page)).

Comment: @Cairnarvon Those are good options too, but σοφία can refer to knowledge, especially practical knowledge of some specific skill or domain (https://outils.biblissima.fr/fr/eulexis-web/?lemma=sofia&dict=LSJ).

Comment: Welcome to the Latin site, Etienne! Your account doesn't get automatically migrated with your question, so you need to extend your Stack Exchange account to this site as well to be able to interact with others. That should be possible with one or two clicks.

Comment: Thank you @Joonas!

Comment: @Cairnarvon It seems epistemogenesis is established jargon in the field of psychology. It might be a possible avenue though I'm unsure if it fits my use-case exactly. (I would elucidate on my use case but it's a self-learning mathematical agent and I think it'd be too long and too off-topic for this conversation, I'm not sure myself what fits best given the agent's conception of "knowledge"/"wisdom".)

Comment: @TKR Having read the definitions of those three terms I am unsure which fits my use-case. This document is also quite interesting on the subject and the potential overlap and differences between the two terms https://sites.temple.edu/dwolf/files/2020/06/Sophia-and-episteme.pdf
If I were to go with sophia, would the compound be as simple as sophiagenesis?

Comment: @Etienne *Sophiagenesis* sounds a bit odd because nouns in -ia don't often appear as the first part of a compound, but it appears there are a handful of such words so it's not unprecedented. I think *sophogenesis* doesn't fit as it would mean "creation/birth of a wise man".

Comment: Stretch/analogize   μυθοπλασία  to    γνωσιπλασία ? Sounds like a neologism from hell, and does not appear attested....

Comment: @Etienne _Gnoseogenesis_ is another option

Comment: John of Damascus (7th century CE) in Against the Jacobites  attests [μυθοπλαστία](https://catholiclibrary.org/library/view?query=μυθοπλαστία&docId=%2FFathers-OR%2FJohn_of_Damascus__Contra_Jacobitas.gr.html&chunk.id=00000015), so you might try γνωσιπλαστία...